# Cell reference for contains value in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

Looking for help referencing another spreadsheet, where I want to lookup several values in cell A2, to see if the value is contained in the cell (as there are variations), then setup an else clause at the end.

First crack isn't parsing:

```
=IF((SomeSheetName!A2=(REGEXMATCH("Johnny","Johnny")),
    (SomeSheetName!A2=(REGEXMATCH("Dan","Dan")),"nosir")))
```

Comment: What is *isn't parsing*? Are you getting a syntax error - then which one? Is the syntax OK, then what are the actual versus expected results?

Comment: Minor update, my formula now is :
=IF(SomeSheetName!A2=(REGEXMATCH("Johnny","Johnny")),
SomeSheetName!A2=(REGEXMATCH("Dan","Dan")),
"nosir")

and I get the ELSE clause, "nosir", but the referenced sheet/cell value is indeed "Johnny".

Comment: OK the REGEXMATCH wasn't working either so trying FIND:

=IF(FIND("Johnny",SomeSheetName!A2,1),"Johnny",
FIND("Dan",SomeSheetName!A2,1),"Dan",
"nosir"
)

still no dice...

Comment: Please add some sample A2 values and the respective expected results.

Comment: Edit all that into your question please. And make sure that the answer to my and Rubens questions is in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(Sheet3!A2 = "Johnny", "Johnny",
 IF(Sheet3!A2 = "Dan"   , "Dan"   , "nosir"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(Sheet3!A2=FILTER(Sheet3!A2, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Johnny*", Sheet3!A2))), "Johnny",
 IF(Sheet3!A2=FILTER(Sheet3!A2, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Dan*"   , Sheet3!A2))), "Dan"   , "nosir"))
```

[image]